# Sampling distributions seem to be quite useless

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, sampling

I am studying estimation and found the concept of sampling distribution hard to grasp. The book I am reading claims that "sampling distributions" answers the following question: how confident should you be in your estimate, e.g. sample mean.

But I felt something wrong intuitively so I conducted the following experiment in Python:

1. I generated 1000 values from a standard normal distribution (actual mean = 0, actual standard deviation = 1) and created a list storing the smallest 10 values (as a particularly non-representative sample of the population of 1000). This is an unlikely but still possible sample.
2. I computed mean and standard deviation from the sample.
3. I generated 1000 new values from a new normal distribution with the sample mean and the sample standard deviation.
4. I plotted the newly generated values in a CDF (shown below).

[image]

The sampling error in this experiment is made big intentionally. (Sampling error is defined as the variation in the estimate caused by random selection.) But sampling error may be big just by chance in real-world scenarios. When sampling error is big, sample mean and sample standard deviation becomes deviated from actual mean and standard deviation, and the sampling distribution plotted with sample mean and sample standard deviation is probably not representative of the goodness of our guess (sample mean in this case).

Now, my question is that, given that sample mean and sample standard deviation can be very unrepresentative (e.g. in this experiment), why do we still use sampling distribution to decide our confidence in estimator? As this experiment shows, it can be very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Comments on your steps:

1. The Central Limit Theorem assumes the sample to be a random sample of the population which is not the case in your example because you systimatically take the 10 lowest data points. This means your results can't confirm what you have read about the sampling distribution since you violate this assumption.
2. This step is okay to my understanding.
3. The CLT does not state that you generate many new distributions from the  mean and sd of one sample. Instead you repeat step one (with random sampling) and step two many times. This gives you a distribution of the estimate you are investigating and the mean of this sampling distribution should be close to your parameter, e.g. a mean of 0.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the word "confidence". I thought "confidence" means the distance between sample mean and actual mean, but it actually means the reliability of an estimate by telling you how much the estimate would vary if you resample again. In short, sampling distributions tell you nothing about whether the sample mean and the actual mean are close. You simply cannot know. That might be why surveyors spend so much time designing surveys to make them representative.

Comment: you are completely right, the whole point of a good survey is to make sure the draws are as random as possible. By the way, you might consider deleting your answer and instead post a comment below igoR87's answer because your statement refers to his/her answer and not to your question.

Comment: As it seems my post answers your question, so please consider marking my post as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You are just sampling form the distribution of the 10 smallest samples out of 1000 samples of a standard normal. This is a well defined distribution. The nonparametric empirical cdf will converge to the true distribution of the joint 10 smallest order statistics. The problem here is about the understanding of what exactly you are estimating with the nonparametric estimator.